# Best method for storing cryptographic secret key and generation of IV in Trivium?

Tags: encryption, keys, stream-cipher, cryptographic-hardware, key-reuse

1. How the secret key for Trivium cipher is stored and managed in an embedded system (IoT sensor node)?
2. How the IV is generated in a Trivium?
3. How to justify the fact that storing a fixed value (for example, the secret key) requires less area size (MROM, PROM etc.) than realizing a normal register for storing the key of same length?

Comment: Not a clear question!.

Comment: In the form asked, (1,2) can only be answered with: it depends on the particular system. The options are...; and then the only thing mildly specific to Trivium follows from its requirement on IV (or lack thereof), some of which can be inferred from the [paper](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/p3ciphers/trivium/trivium_p3.pdf); read §4.5.  For (3). examine what Trivium does with its key bits, and what can be saved by fixing these. Again, that will depend on hardware structure, in particular if there's a specific key register, or a _load key from dense memory_ function, which costs sizably less.